# ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error when accessing Webmin on Scientific Linux 6.2

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I just did a fresh install of Scientific Linux 6.2 with Webmin. Accessing the stock Apache test page via HTTPS port 443 works fine, but when trying to get to Webmin via its standard port 10000 gives me this error:

> Secure Connection Failed
>   An error occurred during a connection to 192.168.56.111:10000.
>
> SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

Note 192.168.56.111 is the server's address in the LAN, but accessing it from the outside gives the same error. I made sure the server's firewall allows port 10000 and turned off SELinux in case that has something to do with it, but that didn't help...

How should I troubleshoot this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error means that the service is not speaking in SSL - for example, if you try to access an http-only service via https. Are you sure that webmin is set up to talk in ssl on port :10000?

What happens if you try to access http://192.168.56.111:10000 ? If that works, then you probably just need to configure webmin to use ssl.

Have you followed all the steps on http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SecuringWebmin#SSL_Encryption, including making sure that the OpenSSL libraries are installed, and the perl module Net::SSLeay?

Comment: YES, that turned out to be my exact problem! After enabling SSL in Webmin (by accessing it through HTTP on port 80), everything seems to work now! Thank you so much for your help.